# Responsive Carousel issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone explain why my Responsive Carousel isn't working?

Here's my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9b9mt0ts/

```js
// When the DOM is ready, run this function
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Set the carousel options
  $('#quote-carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: 4000,
  });
});
```

```css
/* carousel */
#quote-carousel 
{
  padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Control buttons  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control
{
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
/* Previous button  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.left 
{
  left: -12px;
}
/* Next button  */
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.right 
{
  right: -12px !important;
}
/* Changes the position of the indicators */
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators 
{
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: -19px;
}
/* Changes the color of the indicators */
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li 
{
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active 
{
  background: #333333;
}
#quote-carousel img
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px
}
/* End carousel */

.item blockquote {
    border-left: none; 
    margin: 0;
}

.item blockquote img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}



/**
  MEDIA QUERIES
*/

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    #quote-carousel 
    {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    }
    
}

/* Small devices (tablets, up to 768px) */
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    
    /* Make the indicators larger for easier clicking with fingers/thumb on mobile */
    
    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -20px !important;  
    }
    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
        margin: 0px 5px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center'>
    <h2>Responsive Quote Carousel BS3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8'>
      <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
        <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        
        <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
        
          <!-- Quote 1 -->
          <div class="item active">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/overbite.gif" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
                  <!--<img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kolage/128.jpg" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit!</p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
          <!-- Quote 2 -->
          <div class="item">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mijustin/128.jpg" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam auctor nec lacus ut tempor. Mauris.</p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
          <!-- Quote 3 -->
          <div class="item">
            <blockquote>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                  <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/keizgoesboom/128.jpg" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut rutrum elit in arcu blandit, eget pretium nisl accumsan. Sed ultricies commodo tortor, eu pretium mauris.</p>
                  <small>Someone famous</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please expand on "isn't working" ?

Comment: @Jay Absolutely :-) The carousel should work by showing just one item at a time. When I click the top navigation elements it should navigate to the 2nd item but it doesn't. Are you seeing this glitch? :-D

Comment: The console is showing me errors about  HTTPS. Is this the same for you? http://s23.postimg.org/6e3bakxwb/Untitled.png

Comment: Here's how it should work: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-quote-carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the console error. 
Mixed Content: 
**The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/9b9mt0ts/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

[image]

Solution: Access with "**http**" instead "**https**"

Codepen doesn't show an error.

Comment: Hi Rahul! Can you show me it working in  CodePen? :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Also, make sure to load jQuery before Bootstrap JS

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Carousel js file in header.

> http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js

Also check **http** protocol. If your site is not in **https**, then use all external link as **http**

Comment: Brilliant! I now see where I was going wrong - it was so obvious :-D